# CSS' body background-image doesn't work

Tags: html, css, background

The image file (a1.jpg) exists and in the same folder. But it doesn't show up, only the font's color become white.

Anyone can explain me why and how to fix it?

```
<style type="text/css">

p,h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: white; 
}

a { 
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background-image: url('a1.jpg');
}

th,td { 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white; 
}

</style>
```

Comment: its working here http://jsfiddle.net/paVR9/

Comment: Just put `body { background: url(a1.jpg); }`

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.. The title doesn't match your description...

Comment: I'm sorry, background-image, not background-color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your title is right, you need to set a background color before the image. 
It's very unclear what you are asking... Do you want to have a backrgound color and an image?

```
background: #ffffff;
background-image: url('a1.jpg');
```

Comment: An image. The background works, but the background-image doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure, that the name is right? that it is a jpg, not a png? Because your css is valid.. so there must be a problem with or the image, or the directory...

Comment: It's a JPG. The directory and image is fine. That's the problem.

Comment: late response, but did you try is with the quotes?

Comment: I did try with the quotes and without the quotes.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? With the complete code? html and css?

Comment: Hello I see your jsfiddle, with a lot of php, you know you cant use php in a css file?

Comment: No, the CSS is in the HTML file, so, I cut it and put the CSS in the CSS box.

Comment: Oke, last question, do the rest of the css elements work? like the `a, p,h1,h2,h3,h4`

Comment: I found it. Server's fault.

Comment: Uhm, simply saying "server's fault" doesn't really answer the question.  What did you DO to fix?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Wish you would have answered.

Answer (score 2):

the value of the background-image should be like this form and should be in the same folder:

```
background-image:url(../img/1.jpg);
```

Answer (score 1):

`The image file (a1.jpg) is exist and in the same folder ...`

In *which* folder, though? The html page's folder, or the CSS file's folder? The path will only work if the image is in the same folder as the CSS file.

Comment: the script is in the html file, the html file is in the same folder with  the image

Comment: `the html file is in the same folder with the image`. OK, in that case, as said by mdesdev, try `body { background: url(a1.jpg); }`. Also make sure that that's the exact name of the image (all lower case etc.)